# ASP.NET MVC3 & LINQ Select using mapping table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

On SQL I have 3 tables: **Organization(id, name)**, **Category(id, name)**, **Catalog(org_id, cat_id)** - mapping table between Organizations and Categories.
ADO.NET DbContext Generator created for me 2 classes:

```
public partial class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {            
        this.Category = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Organization = new HashSet<Organization>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organization { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I select all organizations that mapped to cat_id = 1 using LINQ**?
Like I do it using t-sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Organization o
INNER JOIN Catalog ct ON o.id = ct.org_id
INNER JOIN Category cg ON ct.cat_id = cg.id
WHERE cg.id = 1
```

I tried

```
var model = _db.Category
            .Where(c => c.id == 1)
            .Select(c => c.Organization);
```

But I have troubles with type defined in view like

```
@model IEnumerable<Project1.Models.Organization>
```

Comment: I cannot find your problem. what do you mean by  having trouble with type in view? please give us more details about your exact problem

Comment: it was error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Project1.Models.Organization]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project1.Models.Organization]'."

Comment: From that error please see my answer. I believe your model is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code there I can only presume that you're not creating an Enumerable from the query. Your code:

```
var model = _db.Category.Where(c => c.id == 1).Select(c => c.Organization);
```

Is not an enumerable as your model is defined. Try:

```
var model = _db.Category.Single(c => c.id == 1).Organizations.ToList();
```

Which will convert the query into an enumeration of the results, which would then satisfy the requirements of your model.

EDIT
On second looks, it appears that your model is not a 1:M relationship, which could be the issue you're having.

Comment: There's a tick next to my answer, click it.